# Titanium TableView with Alternating Row Styles

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am dynamically creating a TableView in which I want alternating TableViewRow styles with distinct layouts, not just a simple background color.

Whichever TableViewRow appears first in my XML displays as a blank row.  For example, keeping the JS constant, if I put contentRowRight above contentRowLeft in my XML, only my odd rows show data (left).  If I swap the view order in XML, then only the even rows show data (right).

I assume either my understanding of controller.getView is wrong or my XML format is missing something.

Javascript code...

```
// Populate table with data
var toggleAlign = true;
data.forEach(function(item) {
    var newRow = Alloy.createController('contentRow', item).getView(toggleAlign ? 'contentRowLeft' : 'contentRowRight');
    $.tblContent.appendRow(newRow);
    toggleAlign = !toggleAlign;
});
```

XML code...

```
<Alloy>
    <TableViewRow id="contentRowRight" class="content-row">
        <View class="thumbnail right">
            <ImageView id="imgThumbnail"></ImageView>
        </View>
        <View class="text-content content-left">
            <Label id="lblTitle"></Label>
            <Label id="lblDate"></Label>
        </View>
    </TableViewRow>

    <TableViewRow id="contentRowLeft" class="content-row">
        <View class="thumbnail left">
            <ImageView id="imgThumbnail"></ImageView>
        </View>
        <View class="text-content content-right">
            <Label id="lblTitle"></Label>
            <Label id="lblDate"></Label>
        </View>
    </TableViewRow>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: What SDK are you using. That was a known problem at some point but should be resolved in last few GAs.

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen I'm using SDK 5.0.0.GA.

Comment: Mmm, then it should be fixed, although it might also be https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-1051. Please create a JIRA ticket with reproducible code/steps/environment.

Comment: Before you do though, I do have some recommendations for your code. For one, try to use Alloy data binding (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding). If you choose not to, then at least don't have two TableViewRows in the XML but instead in the controller add the desired class using addClass() (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Dynamic_Styles-section-37530415_DynamicStyles-ModifyTSSClasses)